# Can you proof trinity by Jesus's words alone?

Tags: life-of-jesus, trinity

Is it possible to prove the concept of Trinity from using the actual sayings of Jesus himself in the bible?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  As a new visitor, I'd recommend checking out the following two posts, which are meant to help newcomers "learn the ropes": [help page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) and [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites).  This question isn't really a good fit for this site.  It's opinion-based, because the level of evidence to qualify as "proof" varies from person to person.

Comment: Wow, 39 minutes between joining the site and saying "Please Delete Me."  It's almost as if you wanted a ask-and-run...

Comment: @AffableGeek it's his profile on several sites. dunno

Comment: @AffableGeek Sorry but what do you mean?

Comment: Your user profile just says "Please Delete Me."  I'm assuming you want your user profile deleted.

Comment: (By the way, I'm not the downvoter.  I didn't upvote, but I didn't downvote either)

Comment: @AffableGeek i have updated my profile thanks.

Comment: Yay!  Glad you are sticking around!  And "hello, world!" to you too!

Answer (score 2):

The bible teaches all over there is **one** God.

> “The most important one,” answered Jesus, “is this: ‘Hear, O Israel: The Lord our God, the Lord is one. Love the Lord your God with all your heart and with all your soul and with all your mind and with all your strength.’
>   [Mark 12:29-30](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Mk%2012:29-30&version=NIV)

The Father and Son are one and fully God:

> I and the Father are one.
>   [John 10:30](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=john%2010:22-30&version=NIV)

The Holy Spirit is God:

> Then Peter said, “Ananias, how is it that Satan has so filled your heart that you have lied to the **Holy Spirit** and have kept for yourself some of the money you received for the land? ... You have not lied just to human beings but to **God**.”
>   [Acts 5:3-4](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts%205:3-4&version=NIV)

Comment: Dang, you beat me to it!!!

Comment: That's not really Trinity, that if you look at it that way would be 2.

Comment: @user1361315 I made an update.